# ggplot: Best way to plot this using R with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Quarter  Team    Year      Units    Sales
2015Q3    A      2015      25000   61.1038751
2015Q3    B      2015       1370    4.5081774
2015Q3    C      2015      19103   34.9492249
2015Q3    D      2015      10757    0.5222169
2015Q3    E      2015       2658    6.0959838
2015Q2    A      2015       2500   10.38751
2015Q2    B      2015        370    3.508
2015Q2    C      2015       1103    2.94
2015Q2    D      2015        757    4.5222169
2015Q2    E      2015        658    5.09
...                                          
2005Q3    A      2015      25000   31.1038751
2005Q3    B      2015       1370    4.5081774
2005Q3    C      2015      12345    4.9492249
2005Q3    D      2015        102    3.5222169
2005Q3    E      2015       2658    5.0959838
```

I have above data set which is quarterly sales by every team. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to plot this so there can be a good visual representation of each teams sales and units gets shown clear per year per quarter basis. I do have large number of teams for example 50.

I was trying to do something like this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Quarter,y=Sales,group=Year))+
  facet_grid(.~Year,scales="free")
```

But this doesn't give a good idea of whats going on. I was going over http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html but unable to grasp how I should plot it.

Comment: If you are grouping by `Year` you probably want to facet by `Team`, or vice versa

Comment: As suggested by fanli faceting by `Team` seems correct but maybe 50 teams are a little bit too much

Comment: If you want to display team sales in units and income over time, I would imagine: x = Time (where Q1 = March, Q2 = June, ...), y = value (`melt` or `gather` the units and sales first), facet = variable, and colour = Team.  If you have 50 teams, that is a lot of data, so perhaps you can use alpha or annotate to highlight the top performers. Alternatively, if you are providing the figures to each team, you can plot other teams as grey points and the team of interest as colored points to see how it performed over time relative to the others.  It all depends on what you are trying to emphasize.

Comment: Flagging to close as opinion based.